# Is it possible to take a screenshot or audio/video recording of a Zoom meeting?

Tags: screenshots, video-recording, audio-recording, zoom-cloud-meetings

When being invited to join a Zoom meeting on an Android phone, is it possible to take a screenshot or audio/video recording of the meeting, using any other applications installed on the phone?